# "X is not dead, it just smells so"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, adverbs, sentence-ends

From what I've found the typical form of this phrase is

> X is not dead, it just smells that way.

Can "that way" be replaced with a *so* in such a position?

> X is not dead, it just smells so.

Comment: Collins' example of this usage (**so** 4. in the state or manner expressed or implied: they're happy and will remain so.) sounds rather better to my ears than the RHK Webster's example (3. in the aforesaid state or condition: It is broken and has long been so.) and much better than the pretentious (to me)-sounding AHD example (1. In the condition or manner expressed or indicated; thus: Hold the brush so.) Though not incorrect, this sense of 'so' often sounds inappropriate. With your sentence, I'd certainly use an alternative. In the US, some of these examples may not sound as high-falutin'.

Comment: The most popular variant seems to be "X isn't dead, it just smells _funny_." Which follows what seems to be the original, Frank Zappa's 1974 quip: _Jazz isn't dead, it just smells funny._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but you probably should not.

There's certainly a meaning of the word *so* that matches perfectly. But is it the meaning that immediately and clearly comes to mind? I don't think so, and I strongly suspect that this is not just my reading of it, but would be common to other readers too.

As such, you could argue that your use was correct, but what's the value in that? One generally doesn't write to have something one can defend as correct, but rather one writes to communicate, and this use of *so* fails to do that here, because the correct sense does not come clearly and immediately to mind.

Comment: If the OP is determined to reword the statement, "X is not dead, it just smells like it" would be a possible alternative. But as you suggest, there is really no good reason to change it just for the sake of changing it.